# Horizontal bar in dreamweaver not working

Tags: c#, php, javascript, jquery, dreamweaver

I have Macromedia Dreamweaver 8 in which my horizontal scrollbar is faded no matter how i write my program .
[See code  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bePNy.png)

I didn't pressed Enter button during writing of my this program but it still doesn't add horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be a settings issue. Go to the `menu -> View -> Code view options -> word wrap` and turn it off.
It is possible that it has another name, I am using the German version of Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

Turn line wrapping off, it's somewhere in those tiny images to the left of your code

edit

or possibly in view > word wrap